# how to shutdown all MessageListenerContainer with Lambda

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming

In a few words, I am trying to write this in lambda syntax:

```
bean = context.getBean(JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.class);
for (MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer : bean.getListenerContainers()) {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = (DefaultMessageListenerContainer) listenerContainer;
    container.shutdown();
}
```

This is my attempt, what is wrong with this Lambda code?

```
context.getBean(JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.class).getListenerContainers()
                  .forEach(DefaultMessageListenerContainer::shutdown());
```

Comment: does the first statement compile, the `()` after `shutdown` have to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close but you need to utilise `map` first to cast all the items to a type `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` then you can iterate over each element of the steam and invoke its `shutdown` method.

```
bean = context.getBean(JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.class);
bean.getListenerContainers().stream().map(e -> (DefaultMessageListenerContainer)e)
                    .forEach(DefaultMessageListenerContainer::shutdown);
```

Also, when using a method reference you cannot use the parenthesis `()` after the method name.